# How to list all the images/videos within a folder from cloudinary in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, api, cloudinary

I'm a newbie to **Node.js**. I've started building an app by cloning the **cloudinary** sample project from [github](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_npm). Then I changed my working directory to photo_album and installed all the dependencies required for the app. And then, I did some changes as per my requirements and made it image and video gallery app.  
 1. **When I try to list all the images within a folder named** *my_photos* **something like [cloudinary support](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/202521082-How-to-list-all-images-within-a-folder-)**

```
cloudinary.api.resources(function(result){console.log(result)}, { type: 'upload', prefix: 'my_photos/' });
```

Then, I'm getting this error

```
/home/fw66/WebstormProjects/cloudinary_npm/samples/photo_album/node_modules/cloudinary/lib/utils.js:1023
          return callback(void 0, result);
                 ^
TypeError: object is not a function
    at /home/fw66/WebstormProjects/cloudinary_npm/samples/photo_album/node_modules/cloudinary/lib/utils.js:1023:18
    at IncomingMessage. (/home/fw66/WebstormProjects/cloudinary_npm/samples/photo_album/node_modules/cloudinary/lib/api.js:103:51)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:944:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:458:13)
```

Process finished with exit code 8 But when I try something like the following, Then, I'm getting the list of all the uploaded images irrespective of the specified folder.

```
cloudinary.api.resources().then(function(result){console.log(result)}, { type: 'upload', prefix: 'my_photos/' });
```

But I need only and only those images which are uploaded inside the folder mentioned above, not outside of it. So, How do I do that?  
 2. **When I try to list all the videos within a folder named** *my_videos* **something like the following**

```
cloudinary.api.resources(function(result){console.log(result)}, { resource_type: 'video', prefix: 'my_videos/' });
```

Then, I'm getting the same error as I did for images above.  
 And when I try something like the following, Then, I'm getting the list of all the uploaded images instead of videos in the api response.

```
cloudinary.api.resources().then(function(result){console.log(result)}, { resource_type: 'video', prefix: 'my_videos/' });
```

I'm not sure what is wrong with my code. Please help me out here.  
 Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using the `cloudinary` is defined using `require('cloudinary').v2` and in that case you should be using a bit different syntax.

Essentially, the callback function should come last and be receiving both `error` and `result` parameters. Also, note that once you provide a parameter hash, a `type` must be provided as well. For example:

```
cloudinary.api.resources({type:"upload",prefix:"my_photos/"}, function(error, result){console.log(error, result)})
```