# Using Cloudinary API from Node.js: retrieving resources from a specific folder fails with both cloudinary.v2 and Axios

Tags: node.js, axios, resources, cloudinary

**No other Stack Overflow solutions work for me** (two most relevant examples I found: [How to list all the images/videos within a folder from cloudinary in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36718734/how-to-list-all-the-images-videos-within-a-folder-from-cloudinary-in-node-js), [NodeJS cloudinary search API by context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64841164/nodejs-cloudinary-search-api-by-context)) to solve the problem stated in this question's title: in Node.js, I fail to **retrieve data for the resources from a specific folder** ('entiMediatici' in the code below, containing 19 images) both if I try retrieving them **by accessing Cloudinary API via Cloudinary.v2 or Axios**.
*While I could simply store their URLs in MongoDB and load those as img src in my view, it feels overkill to create a collection ad hoc, since they are a bunch of relatively unimportant assets within the logic of the site I am developing; thus, I prefer to fetch their URLs from the cloud instead.*
Therefore, I show four different code chunks I wrote to try that here below, hoping someone can help me. *Each chunk logs an empty list of results.*

```
/////////////////////////// SOLUTION 1: Axios get A (within async func)
    const {data} = await axios.get('https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/<cloudname>/resources/image/upload?sub_folder=entiMediatici', {
        auth: {
        username: process.env.cloudKey,
        password: process.env.cloudSecret
        }
    });
    console.log(data);
    //////////////////////// SOLUTION 2: Axios post A
    axios.post(`https://${process.env.cloudKey}:${process.env.cloudSecret}@api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/<cloudname>/resources/search`, {
        "expression": "folder=entiMediatici/*"
    }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
    }).catch(err=>{console.log(err);
    });
    //////////////////////// SOLUTION 3: Axios get B
    axios.get(`https://${process.env.cloudKey}:${process.env.cloudSecret}@api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/<cloudname>/resources/image/context?folder=entiMediatici`).then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
    }).catch(err=>{console.log(err);
    });
    //////////////////////// SOLUTION 4: Admin API
    cloudinary.search.expression(
        'folder:entiMediatici/*' // add your folder
        ).sort_by('public_id','desc').max_results(100).execute().then(result=>console.log(result));
    ////////////////////////
```

Thanks!

Comment: The SearchAPI expression field would need to follow some guidelines as [indicated in the documentation](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/search_api#expressions) (e.g., `expression=folder:entiMediatici`). The query parameter for the POST method would be: `https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/<your_cloud>/resources/search?expression=folder:entiMediatici`.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE: SOLUTIONS (for AXIOS) and a follow-up question**

Cloudinary support kindly provided me with the **correct syntax for Axios**, i.e., in the Axios POST request, `folder` is meant to be followed by `:` not `=`. Furthermore, in case the target is a subfolder (as in my case), it is necessary to provide the full path. In light of their example, I modified my code as follows. I post this answer in case others are facing a similar problem.

```
axios.post(`https://${process.env.cloudKey}:${process.env.cloudSecret}@api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/<cloudname>/resources/search`, {
            "expression": "folder:<first folder in home>/<subfolder>/entiMediatici"
        }).then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data);
        }).catch(err=>{console.log(err);
        });
```

The solution by **epasos_573**, whom I thank, works the same. In my case, adapting the code he provided is:

```
axios.post(`https://${process.env.cloudKey}:${process.env.cloudSecret}@api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/<cloudname>/resources/search?expression=folder:<first folder in home>/<subfolder>/entiMediatici`).then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data);
        }).catch(err=>{console.log(err);
        });
```

So, my *follow-up question* is: **given both syntaxes work, are there differences between the two that may let one prefer one over the other?**